# How to get the H-index using Scopus API

Tags: citations, scopus

I Want to get the H-index of an author through Scopus API, the problem is I tried author retrieval API and Scopus search API using Author ID and none of them contain the H- index, so is there another API get the H-index using Author ID or should I calculate it?

This is the APIs I used:

```
 https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=au-id%287xxxxxx9&apiKey=xxxxxx

https://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/xxxxx?apiKey=xxxxxx
```